# Method in Entity need to load all data from aggregate, how to optimalize this?

Tags: spring, hibernate, service, entity, domain-driven-design

I've problem with aggregate which one will increase over time.
One day there will be thousands of records and optimalization gonna be bad.

```
@Entity
public class Serviceman ... {

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "servicemanList")
  private List<ServiceJob> services = new ArrayList<>();

  ...


public Optional<ServiceJob> firstServiceJobAfterDate(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        return services.stream().filter(i -> i.getStartDate().isAfter(dateTime))
                .min(Comparator.comparing(ServiceJob::getStartDate));
    }

}
```

Method just loading all ServiceJob to get just one of them.
Maybe I should delegate this method into service with native sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to design small aggregates instead of large ones.

This essay explains in detail how to do it: http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/. It explains how to decompose your aggregates to smaller ones so you can manage the complexity.

In your case instead of having an Aggregate consisting of two entities: **Serviceman** and **Servicejob** with **Serviceman** being the aggregate root you can decompose it in two smaller aggregates with single entity. **ServiceJob** will reference Serviceman by ID and you can use **ServicejobRpository** to make queries.

In your example you will have **ServicejobRpository.firstServiceJobAfterDate(guid servicemanID, DateTime date)**.

This way if you have a lot of entities and you need to scale, you can store Servicejob entities to another DB Server.

If for some reason **Serviceman** or **Servicejob** need references to each other to do their work you can use a **Service** that will use **ServicemanRepository** and **ServicejobRepository** to get both aggregates and pass them to one another so they can do their work.